# get_the_category listing in hierarchial order

Tags: posts, loop, hierarchical, categories

Hello at the moment I'm wondering how I would be able to make this work to post in Hierarchical order within the post loop.

```
<?php 
    foreach ((get_the_category()) as $childcat) 
    { 
        if (cat_is_ancestor_of('42', $childcat)) 
        { 
            echo '<li> <a href="'.get_category_link($childcat->cat_ID).'">'; echo $childcat->cat_name . '</a> </li>'; 
        }
    }
?>
```

I would like it to output as such:

- Parent

  - Child
  - Child

    - Grandchild

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `wp_list_categories` instead,

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
    'hierarchical'       => true,
    'child_of'            => 42,   //parent category
    'hide_empty'         => 1,    //hide empty categories (set to 0 to show)
    );

    wp_list_categories($args); 

?>
```

A full list of parameters for `wp_list_categories` can be found [**HERE**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

As you can see its highly customizable simply by adding extra arguements to the array stored in the `$args` variable that we later pass to the `wp_list_categories` function.

Note: Adding the `child_of => ID` argument you can specify the parent ID of the category for which you want to retrieve category terms for. Be aware that if there are no posts in the parent category, it will not show, in which case you may try setting `hide_empty => 0` instead.

## UPDATE

Well, instead of writing this from scratch myself, **Scribu** already has thankfully, so please take a look at the following link for more details;

http://scribu.net/wordpress/extending-the-category-walker.html

Comment: Problem with wp_list_categories is it lists all the categories but not like get_the_category that pulls from the current post.

Comment: Ok sorry, I read your opening sentence differently than that.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it!

Comment: Late reply but I forgot to approve, my apology!

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort the categories to make sure they come in the correct order:

```
// get categories of post in sorted order
$categories = sortCategories(get_the_category());     

function sortCategories($categories) { // Sorting the category
    usort($categories, "cmpCategories");
    return $categories;
}

function cmpCategories($category_1,$category_2) { // Sort function
    foreach(get_categories(array("parent" => $category_1->cat_ID)) AS $sub) {
        if($category_2->cat_ID == $sub->cat_ID) return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @tobidude's great solution, a complete exemple:

Create the functions

```
function sortCategories($categories) { // Sorting the category
    usort($categories, "cmpCategories");
    return $categories;
}

function cmpCategories($category_1,$category_2) { // Sort function
    foreach(get_categories(array("parent" => $category_1->cat_ID)) AS $sub) {
        if($category_2->cat_ID == $sub->cat_ID) return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Call your WP_Query... and during the loop call the get_the_category() inside the function sortCategories:

```
$sub_cat = sortCategories(get_the_category());
```

Before print the category, I created a conditional to get the deepest category:

```
if(isset($sub_cat[2])):
  echo $sub_cat[2]->name;
elseif(isset($sub_cat[1])):
  echo $sub_cat[1]->name;
else:
  echo $sub_cat[0]->name;
endif;
```